# Bottle, how to get_cookie during AJAX request (same domain)

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, cookies, xmlhttprequest, bottle

I use bottle set/get cookie mecanism to track my user_id (with 'secret' param when calling set/get_cookie()
During normal http(s) request everything is fine but when making a xhr request (same domain)`user_id = request.get_cookie('user_id', secret='mysecret')` returns None.
When checking on client browser, cookie and key/value are still available.

How to deal with it ?
(I've always been told that xhr requests are http requests, so from same domain, cookies should be shared, no ? is problem arrising from Bottle 'secret' handling ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states, when setting a cookie the default path is "/"
https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-cookies

> path: Limit the cookie to a given path (default: /)

But the code comment says default is "current path" e.g. `/XXX/dev`
https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L1796

> :param path: limits the cookie to a given path (default: current path)

Based on this behaviour we can assume the later is true.

So when setting the cookie, if you want any path to have access to the cookie from your domain. Set the path in your cookie as "/"

`set_cookies('test', 123, secret='mysecret', path='/')`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to `set_cookies('test', 123, secret='mysecret')` under AJAX request, it worked, but still couldn't find previous cookies.

Then I remarked that my previous cookies, called cook1 and cook2, written under 'normal' http request, if they had same domain, had different 'path' (under Chrome ressource explorer). They were set under path '/XXX/dev' and my AJAX request was just under path '/XXX'
So I modified my AJAX request from /XXX/do_stuff to point to '/XXX/dev/do_stuff', and then, surprise ! cook1 and cook2 could be read by my AJAX request.

Not sure if it's a Bottle bug or if such behaviour is designed on purpose (in this case, if someone can explain to me why...), but at least I have my solution.